# jQuery Facebox delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebox

I need a very FAST and lightweight jquery based Modal box on my site, I am looking at Facebox http://famspam.com/facebox

It is a nice plugin and it seems fast and lightweight but I think I can still strip out some of the features I do not need.  For example I do not need it to use regex and find photos, so I have removed that part of the code, also I do not want the box to close whenever you click anywhere or the escape key.  I have this partially done, I removed the code that makes the escape key close the box but I have not figured out how to make it only close programaticly or when clicking the close button only, right now it closes on any click outside of the box.

Now I have one issue I have not been able to figure out yet, there appears to be 2 spots in the code that control the delay of fading the box in and out, they were set at 200 and I changed them to 0 and tried several other number combinations but I can not seem to get the speed to be faster (less delay).

Does anyone know how to remove the delay in opening a facebox?  Also how to disable it from closing when you click anywhere outside of the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable closing it from clicking anywhere outside, 
you can find something called `"overlay      : true"`
change it to `"overlay      : false,"`

To close it with-out delay, You can find something like `'$(document).bind('close.facebox', function() {'`
there, change

`"$('#facebox').fadeOut(function() {"`

to

`"$('#facebox').hide(function() {"`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hacking facebox, I would try something more configurable.

I've used [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/) to create modal boxes, which display instantly, can't be closed except when certain conditions are met, etc

Answer (score 0):

I use the [thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) for one project, pretty fast. Check also this [list](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/18/30-best-solutions-for-image-galleries-slideshows-lightboxes/). I recommend you to keep the closing by clicking outside the box option, a real help for users.